# Data is not grouped correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have source array with names of countries and other array with products. Indicies of both arrays are equal.

```
array1:{China, China, Korea, USA, USA},

array2:{Lenovo, Asus, Samsung, Apple, Blackberry},

result : array : {{China, {Lenovo, Asus}}, {Korea, {Samsung}} ... }
```

But I cant group arrays correctly. I always get a result

```
{{China, {Lenovo}},{China, {Asus}} ... }.
```

My code is :

```
for (i = 0; i < XArray.length; i++) {
    var pointsArray = [];

    for (j = 0; j < XArray.length; j++) {

        if (XArray[i] == XArray[j]) {
            pointsArray.push([parseFloat(YArray[i]), parseFloat(ZArray[i])]);
        }
    }

    dataSource.push({
        name: i,
        data: pointsArray.slice()
    });
    pointsArray.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using 2 arrays instead of a JSON object?

Comment: If USA Then array should be :  USA{Apple, Blackberry}  right

Comment: Do really want: `[{China: [Lenovo, Asus]}, {Korea: [Samsung]} ...`?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use an object to group manufacturers by country. Like this:

```
var conutries,
    manufacturers,
    i,
    len,
    country,
    manufacturerByCountry;
countries = ['China', 'China', 'Korea', 'USA', 'USA'];
manufacturers = ['Lenovo', 'Asus', 'Samsung', 'Apple', 'Blackberry'];
len = countries.length;
manufacturerByCountry = {};
// expected result:
// array : {'China': ['Lenovo', 'Asus'], 'Korea': ['Samsung'] ... }

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    country = countries[i];
    if(!manufacturerByCountry[country]) {
        manufacturerByCountry[country] = [];
    }
    manufacturerByCountry[country].push(manufacturers[i]);
}

console.log(manufacturerByCountry);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/gdnRy/)

---

If you still want to get the result you've described in question, then you can go with the solution like this:

```
var conutries,
    manufacturers,
    i,
    len,
    country,
    manufacturerByCountry,
    countryIndex,
    index;
countries = ['China', 'China', 'Korea', 'USA', 'USA'];
manufacturers = ['Lenovo', 'Asus', 'Samsung', 'Apple', 'Blackberry'];
len = countries.length,
manufacturerByCountry = [],
countryIndex = {};
// expected result:
// array : [[China, [Lenovo, Asus]], [Korea, [Samsung]] ... ]

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    country = countries[i];
    if(countryIndex[country] === undefined) {
        index = manufacturerByCountry.push([country, []]) - 1;
        countryIndex[country] = index;
    } else {
        index = countryIndex[country];
    }
    manufacturerByCountry[index][1].push(manufacturers[i]);
}

console.log(manufacturerByCountry);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/662JZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about the syntax, but I think you're trying to do this:

```
var array1 = ['China', 'China', 'Korea', 'USA', 'USA'];
var array2 = ['Lenovo', 'Asus', 'Samsung', 'Apple', 'Blackberry'];
var result = [];
var name, names = {};
var nameCount = 0;
var obj;

for (var i=0, iLen=array1.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  name = array1[i];

  // If haven't found name already, setup structure
  // so value can be added after the block
  if (!(name in names)) {

    // Add name to the list of names and remember its index
    names[name] = nameCount;

    // Create a new object
    obj = {};

    // Give it a property with value of name and assign an array
    obj[name] = [];

    // Add it to results
    result.push(obj);

    // Increment index for next time
    ++nameCount;
  }

  // Add member of array2 to name object's array
  result[names[name]][name].push(array2[i]);
}
```

which creates an array of objects like:

```
[
  {China: ['Lenovo', 'Asus']},
  {Korea: ['Samsung']},
  {USA:   ['Apple', 'Blackberry']}
]
```